# Is this possible anymore? PHP Switch call on function

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

Hey guys thanks for the time looking at this project I'm working on! It was an old project that I had semi-working 2 years ago but now isn't doing me a whole lot. I'm hoping you can save me from a lot of time rewriting this!

Anyway it's a smaller project that I'm looking to ioncube and instead of paying per file I used to be able to use a switch and call on several different functions within one file.

Anyway here's a basic mockup of what I'm trying to do. Like I said currently it isn't working. When I point the browser to `index.php?action=calendar` it's blank as well as all the other classes.

```
<?php
include 'theme/header.php';
?>
<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
YES LOGGED IN
<?php
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    echo $action;

    switch($action){
        case "calendar":
            calendar();
            break;
        default:
            index();
            break;
    }

    function index()
        { 
            echo "Hello";
        }

    function calendar()
        {
            include 'calendar.php';
            $calendar = new Calendar();
            echo $calendar->show();
        }
<?php else : ?>
NOT LOGGED IN
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
include 'theme/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page, that should tell you what error is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the help, after enabling I forgot that when I modified the code I moved the switch to the top which was calling the function before it was printed. So I just moved it back down and now all is good!